# how to compress content so that they fit inside DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xml-parsing

in my webApp i am receiving following from xml

```
<XMLNode>
      <b><font color='#2C5E87' size='13pt'>blah blah</font></b>
      <br>
      </textformat>
      <textformat blockindent='-15'>
      <li>blah</li>


      <b><font color='#2C5E87' size='13pt'>blah blah blah</font></b>
      <br>
      </textformat>
      <textformat blockindent='-15'>
      <li>blah blah</li>

      </textformat>
      <b><font color='#2C5E87' size='13pt'>blah blah blah</font></b>
      <br>
      <textformat leading='-1'>
      <p>blah blah blah blah blah blah </p>
      </textformat>
    </XMLNode>
```

now i want to display content inside `<XMLNode></XMLNode>` in a fixed sized Div 
my javaScript code is

```
var temp = $(xml).find("XMLNode").text();
$("#DIV_ID").html(temp);
```

theoretically it should work but Text is huge and can not fit inside my DIV.

CSS of my Div is,

```
#DIV_ID
{
    position:absolute;
    top:10px;
    height:200px;
    width:250px;
    top:32px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

what is problem here ??   how can i compress text to fit in that DIV. i am currently trying it on IE8

Comment: What do you mean by compress?

Comment: shrink !!!!!

text size should be 13 but browser is displaying something like 30px... but still in "Developer tool" in IE i can see font is 13
i am confuse !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make new CSS rule in your CSS:

```
#DIV_ID b font {font-size: 10px !important;}
```

Comment: as i can't edit xml,i think this is only way to show contents correctly !!!!

thanx for u r solution !

Answer (score 2):

You have a lot of weird stuff in your HTML:

```
<XMLNode>
      <b><font color='#2C5E87' size='13pt'>blah blah</font></b>
      <br>
      </textformat>
      ...
```

So  you close the `</textformat>` but you hadn't opened it..?

And I don't know which doctype you are using but the `<font>` element is deprecated in HTML 4.01. And why would you even use it? The content in your XMLNode is pretty bad html.

For instance you also have `<li>blah</li>`. But your listitem is not included inside an (un)ordered list such as :

```
<ul>
   <li>blah</li>
</ul>
```

So why don't you replace all that html with simple but efficient `<p>` tags and `<strong>` instead of `<b>` so you can all easily control it in your CSS.

That HTML is simply asking to be badly interpreted. So cleaning that up would fix it all.

Like so:

```
<XMLNode>
      <p class="strong">blah blah</p>
      <ul>
          <li>blah</li>
      </ul>

      <p class="strong">blah blah blah</p>
      <ul>
          <li>blah blah</li> 
      </ul>

      <p class="strong">blah blah blah</p>
      <p>blah blah blah blah blah blah</p>
</XMLNode>
```

CSS:

```
#div_id {
    position:absolute;
    top:10px;
    height:200px;
    width:250px;
    top:32px;
    overflow:hidden;
}

p {
    color: #2C5E87;
    font-size: 14px;
}

p.strong {
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Comment: i am agree with you !  Xml has lot of weird things !!!   but it is coming from Ajax call & content of that xml might get change, so i can't write fixed rules to replace content of that xml, instead i need something that can just show text properly.  because origin of that xml (server) is not in my control

Comment: @SauB That is weird. Who controls the XML content? Not you? So what if you fix it now by adding some CSS. Then suddenly the XML becomes `<p style="font-size: 80px;">...</p>`. No matter what you did in your CSS, this will be overwritten by the inline CSS and your page is screwed. So make agreements and make sure they at least provide syntax-correct HTML.

Answer (score 1):

About the [font](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/font) `size` attribute:

> > This attribute specifies the font size as either a numeric or relative value. Numeric values range from 1 to 7 with 1 being the smallest and 3 the default. It can be defined using a relative value, like +2 or -3, which set it relative to the value of the size attribute of the  element, or relative to 3, the default value, if none does exist.

No `pt` or `px` value is allowed.

Additional you should read following from the [same page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/font) about the font-tag:

> > Do not use this element! Though once normalized in HTML 3.2, it was deprecated in HTML 4.01, at the same time as all elements related to styling only, then obsoleted in HTML 5.

Use CSS to define the font-size, e.g.:

```
font-size: 10px;
```

Comment: +1. I haven't seen the <font> tag used for years. Remove that and style it up using CSS as Jules has suggested

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `px` instead of `pt`? so `size='13px'`, `pt` is used for printing and should not be used for screen font sizes.

Comment: yes !! i tried that by replacing "pt" by "px" in receiving text
`temp = temp.replace("pt","px");`

but it is of no use